# Nexus 5 in Recovery mode not detected in ADB but another Nexus 5 gets detected

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, adb, custom-roms, unbricking

I think I soft bricked my Nexus 5.

I was planning on wiping all data from Nexus 5 and installing Cyanogenmod 12.1 following the normal procedure in the Recovery Mode but the wiping got stuck at Wiping Cache for very long and I ended up rebooting the phone.

My phone has ever since been showing "Unable to mount /cache" error.

To fix everything I thought of installing a Stock ROM image from ADB but my phone does not get detected under the devices list when I run "adb devices"

I have installed the drivers and to test I connected another Nexus 5 which did appear in the list but my phone does not.

Any ideas on how I can proceed to fix this issue.

Any suggestions or help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Because you want to install a new ROM you wouldn't mind erasing your cache partition from scratch. You can try a fastboot ROM and erase+make the cache partition using the fastboot flash command. Otherwise, fastboot has the erase partition parameter as well. IDK how to use it, may be Google can help here. // This would be possible only when your device is detected in fastboot mode on PC. What's the status?

Comment: That is exactly where I am stuck. I have manually installed the drivers. Other Nexus 5 gets detected in adb and fastboot but mine does not. When I do "_adb devices_" my phone does not show up. :(

Comment: There are devices that doesn't show up in ADB devices but in fastboot mode. Fastboot will show devices only when the device is booted into fastboot mode and not into Android system. Have you confirmed all these scenarios? If nothing works, I advise looking for some low-level flashing tool which doesn't depend upon fastboot or ADB.

Comment: hi Firelord.. i got it to work. the problem was with my usb cable i think.. it intermittently disconnected my phone from the laptop and that ended up in windows thinking of my phone as an unrecognized device.. thanks for all the help though.. appreciated.. :)

Comment: Great! Please mention this part as an answer so that a reader doesn't have to look into comments to see the gist.

Comment: Yup. Posted it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. The problem was with my USB cable. It intermittently disconnected my phone from the laptop and that ended up in windows thinking of my phone as an unrecognized device.

I manually installed the drivers for ADB Composite Device and then fired "adb devices" and it showed up.

Thanks Firelord for your help.

Really appreciated. :)